# Which Data type is best to store ndarray in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, face-recognition

I am new to python. I am trying to store encoded face -recognition data to postgresql .data having numpy.ndarray type.how to store it to database

I have created table in postgresql with datatype float array to store this kind of data.
[-0.18851721  0.1335005   0.05511604 -0.06277356 -0.02851189  0.05052128
 -0.07445884 -0.13722856  0.1954176  -0.06740481  0.25077775  0.10245039
 -0.18124828 -0.16744739 -0.00625956  0.12364798 -0.16207671 -0.1176396
 -0.1011513  -0.10095926  0.03207059  0.04325461  0.09359518  0.02856386
 -0.13979232 -0.36666855 -0.07963274 -0.17080374 -0.02638249 -0.1269975
 -0.0090007   0.02657734 -0.20248355 -0.09234729  0.02776779  0.02405531
  0.00760813  0.00992479  0.19022804  0.06206769 -0.09040014  0.05418085
  0.064793    0.22478105  0.25524226  0.06918503 -0.02772347 -0.06143937
  0.11962473 -0.21881692  0.06122055  0.16483036  0.06817284  0.05840653
  0.13647863 -0.15373509  0.02558955  0.07045594 -0.14521058  0.03485384
 -0.00699617 -0.09832785 -0.09840143  0.03895607  0.15690036  0.10940056
 -0.09321431 -0.10966937  0.13620195 -0.00220358 -0.03094646  0.05223915
 -0.17761797 -0.18311672 -0.21710058  0.09066689  0.38883513  0.1444997
 -0.23706336  0.01360968 -0.16185056 -0.01500403  0.00909736 -0.00461302
 -0.04799315 -0.12826051 -0.05354946  0.00862529  0.09347358  0.08640108
 -0.03517354  0.24804059 -0.02498217  0.03270505  0.03874825  0.06522777
 -0.1336177  -0.01356841 -0.16400115 -0.10731176  0.03216686 -0.01949028
 -0.00452124  0.08888718 -0.23588364  0.11363064  0.01547772 -0.03120285
 -0.01432095 -0.00138823 -0.07527658  0.03971821  0.10038127 -0.25322253
  0.28212106  0.21040824  0.00970344  0.17483208  0.10048124  0.01512941
 -0.00569613 -0.01414334 -0.12674388 -0.12199711  0.0511818   0.00163262
  0.02390176  0.00650601]

```
import face_recognition
import psycopg2
import numpy

con = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="root", 
host="127.0.0.1", port="5432",database="testdb")
con.autocommit = True
print("Database opened successfully")
cur = con.cursor()
known_image = 
face_recognition.load_image_file("/home/cygnet/Pictures/o1.jpeg")
biden_encoding = (face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0])
arr=numpy.array(biden_encoding,numpy.float128)
print(arr)
cur.execute("insert into img2(id,img) values(%s,%s)",(1,arr))
```

it gives me and error like 
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'numpy.ndarray'
kindly guide me  which data type i need in postgresql to store  numpy.ndarray or how to store this data in postgresql.

Comment: How is your database table defined?

Comment: id is in Integer and image in float []

Comment: Float is only stored in 4 bytes, so decimal places will be truncated if you use that value. For those numbers it looks like you will want to use  `double precision[]` or `float8[]` to store those numbers, or if they are still missing precision `numeric[]`

Comment: I tried it with float,numeric and double precision but it still gives me same error. the data type it returns is Float 64 and if i try to insert into double precision it gives me same error.